# Various sci-fi themes

Tags: science-fiction, theme

What are some specific sci-fi themes I could use to structure my story?
I have some parts about a sci-fi story here and there written down but I can't put them in the bigger picture.

What I know for sure, is a diagalactic war to be included.

I have thought, maybe from conflicting colonies that want independence..

Are there some existing themes I could use?

I want a bigger theme so I can insert my specifics.

Comment: I think this might be better suited to WorldBuilders SE.

Comment: Perhaps try http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScienceFiction

Comment: @LaurenIpsum it would need to be a lot more focused, and about the setting rather than the writing, to work on WorldBuilding.

Answer (score 1):

Sci-fi relies on:

humans vs other -- aliens, viruses, etc.

good vs evil e.g. Star Wars

nature vs capitalist disregared of nature

black vs white

technology is good/bad

Pick a theme related to the above. For example, 'Humans will succeed in the face of difficulty.' 'The human race is superior to all others.'

Answer (score 1):

Science fiction is, as a guide futuristic but that doesn't mean you can't use the past to help you with your idea.

Take for example the USA's battle for independence from Great Britain.  It was a colony that fought for freedom.  As many others have as well throughout our history.

With that idea, do some research into what too place (and why), change the setting to the future with spaceships, colonies on distant worlds, futuristic weapon technology.

Do remember though that your story has to be something your readers can relate to and as a result the setting becomes less important.  If you spend pages detailing the amazing worlds and colonies but your story and characters are dull, no-one is going to be interested.